# WebLogic Class Cast on EJB Home Interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

We are upgrading a J2EE application (EJB 2.0) from WebLogic Service 8.1 to 12c(12.2.1.1.0). We are building an exploded EAR to a directory in the domain directory. A web application (struts) performs a lookup in JNDI and gets a reference to an EJB and returns a home class just fine. The problem we have is it cannot be cast to the interface.

Using reflection we can see that the returned class does implement the expected interface, but it always throws a java.lang.ClassCastException when we try to cast it.

The working theory is that one class loader is used to support the EJBs in the container and another unrelated class loader services the servlets so the returned class cannot be cast into the interface class from another class loader. We cannot confirm this, but we suspect the class loader hierarchy has changed between WLS 8.1 and 12c. If that is the case, we cannot find a way around this.

We have started using the WebLogic Classloader Analysis Tool, but it is not indicating problems with any class involved with this particular case.

The core question is what do we have to change to enable the cast to work like WebLogic 8.1 so we can avoid refactoring the existing code?

To be clear, the code works in WebLogic Server 8.1 but does not in WebLogic Server 12c. The EJB deployment descriptors have been updated with weblogic.DDConverter, but we were experiencing this problem before the conversion as well.

This is how we lookup the EJB in the JndiHelper class (this works with WLS8):

```
public static EJBHome getHome( String ejbHomeName ) throws NamingException {
  EJBHome home = null;
  String sENCHome = JNDI_ENC_EJB_CONTEXT + "/" + ejbHomeName;
  Object objRef = new InitialContext().lookup( sENCHome );
  home = (EJBHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow( objRef, EJBHome.class );
  return home;
}
```

Here is the code which calls the above, makes the cast, and prints out diagnostic information if it fails:

```
EJBHome home = null;
try {
  home = JndiHelper.getHome( JndiConstants.USER_HANDLER_EJB );
  UserHandlerHome userHandlerHome = (UserHandlerHome)home; // throws class cast exception here
  UserHandler userHandler = userHandlerHome.create();
  adminInd = userHandler.isAdmin( userId );
} catch ( ClassCastException e ) {
  StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer( "ClassCastException: " );
  b.append( e.getMessage() );
  b.append( "\r\nThe JNDI lookup for '" );
  b.append( JndiConstants.USER_HANDLER_EJB );
  b.append( "' returned a bean of unexpected type.\r\nValue:" );
  b.append( home );
  b.append( "\r\nReturned bean's inheritance:\r\n" );
  b.append( Reflector.getInheritanceDump( home ) );
  b.append( "\r\n" );
  b.append( UserHandlerHome.class.getName() );
  b.append( " expected.\r\nFull Stack Trace:\r\n" );
  b.append( ExceptionUtil.stackTrace( e ) );
  Logger.error( this, b.toString() );
  errors.add( ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new WebActionError( MessageConstants.NON_DESCRIPT_ERROR, WebActionError.makePopUp( b.toString() ) ) );
}
```

Here is a sample of the diagnostic information displayed. Note the inheritance list contains types and interfaces suffixed with "(I)":

```
ERROR com.myapp.admin.controller.UserHelper - ClassCastException: com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandler_8cwrmw_HomeImpl cannot be cast to com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandlerHome
The JNDI lookup for 'UserHandler' returned a bean of unexpected type.
Value:com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandler_8cwrmw_HomeImpl@5f938f12
Returned bean's inheritance:
com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandler_8cwrmw_HomeImpl
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessEJBHome
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseEJBHome
java.lang.Object
weblogic.ejb.container.interfaces.BaseEJBRemoteHomeIntf(I)
weblogic.ejb.container.interfaces.BaseEJBHomeIntf(I)
weblogic.ejb.spi.BaseEJBHomeIntf(I)
weblogic.ejb20.interfaces.RemoteHome(I)
javax.ejb.EJBHome(I)
java.rmi.Remote(I)
weblogic.ejb.spi.RemoteHome(I)
weblogic.rmi.SupportsInterfaceBasedCallByReference(I)
com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandlerHome(I)
com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandlerHome expected.
Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandler_8cwrmw_HomeImpl cannot be cast to com.myapp.admin.model.UserHandlerHome
        at com.myapp.admin.controller.UserHelper.isAdmin(UserHelper.java:82)
        at com.myapp.framework.controller.login.LoginAction.doAction(LoginAction.java:278)
        at com.myapp.framework.controller.AfgAction.perform(AfgAction.java:268)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionPerform(ActionServlet.java:1888)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1654)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:526)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3679)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

In our WEB-INF\weblogic.xml we have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app>

    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <backward-compatible>true</backward-compatible>
    </jsp-descriptor>

    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <!-- Resolves finding Log4J classes (Issue T9) -->
            <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.log4j.pattern.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.log4j.net.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.log4j.jmx.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.log4j.jdbc.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.log4j.helpers.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.log4j.config.*</package-name>
            <!-- Recommended by the Classloader Analysis Tool to resolve reported conflicts -->
            <package-name>com.myapp.admin.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.myapp.framework.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.myapp.om.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.sun.mail.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.mail.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.mail.event.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.mail.internet.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.mail.search.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.wsdl.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.wsdl.extensions.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.wsdl.factory.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.wsdl.xml.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.xml.rpc.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this issue by removing `<prefer-application-packages>` from `weblogic.xml` which was causing the `weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader` to load its own version of the interface along with its parent the `weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader` which supported the application. Since the web application was trying to cast to a version of the interface which did not match that in the EJB resolved by a different class loader, the cast was not allowed.